# Android tablet BROWSER memory analyser

Tags: memory-management, android-widget, profiler, android

My .Net web site application is working fine with IE(6-8). But it eats up memory in android tablet BROWSER,poor responsive and often crashing. It could be CSS/JavaScript/unnecessary event handler or whatsoever issue. Is there any widget/profiler availble to analyse memory consumption? Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html

Comment: @zapl, Is it related with android code or android browser

Comment: It is analyzing Android Brower / Apps, not the webcontent. You should be able to debug browser (maybe only on emulator - apps need to be debuggable) or an app with a simple WebView that way too. I don't know if it is helpful for finding what you search since it is not specifically meant to profile the browser and it may miss some information since browser includes a lot of native code.

Comment: will it show me the javascript object memory usage?

Comment: no, the memory consumption of the whole browser - maybe you can derive something about javascript mem consumption from that.